# Read Logs programmatically in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, logging

For one of my Blackberry applications I need to read Logs / Eventlogs. How can I read those logs from my application. Is it possible to read the logs programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible to do programmatically. If you have access to device you could get them manually.

Comment: I wonder how there people are doing all these things that are not possible in BB http://www.mobile-spy.com/compatibility.html

Comment: I don't see that this app reads BlackBerry device logs which are logged with EventLogger class

Comment: Really its not possible?? The how different spy apps are working ??

Comment: Can you name spy app?

Comment: @EugenMartynov .. see this:: http://www.stealthgenie.com/ ,,, http://www.mpsy.com/  .. and many more...

Comment: Don't you mix call, email, sms, etc logs with blackberry event log which is written by usage EventLog class from applications?